# In modern Linux x86-64 is it safe for userspace to overwrite the GS register?

Tags: linux, assembly, pthreads, x86-64, memory-segmentation

In a 64-bit C program, using glibc, pthreads and so on (nothing exotic), is it safe to overwrite the GS register, without restoring it, on current kernel and glibc versions? I know that the *FS* register is used by pthreads/glibc for the thread-local storage block pointer, so messing with that will wreck anything that uses TLS, but I'm not sure about GS

If not, is safe to save the value, overwrite it, and then restore the value, as long as the userland code while it is overwritten doesn't do X (what is X)?

Comment: Yes, but instead of doing that you will likely want `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_GS, foo);`

Comment: @Jester - normally, maybe yeah - but here I want to use this as a dirty hack to detect interrupts (which reset fs and gs as described [here](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2018/01/observing-interrupts-from-userland-on-x86.html)), as part of profiling something else, so avoiding a system call (which I assume `arch_prtrl` uses under the covers) is required.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure; Jester says "Yes, but instead of doing that you will likely want `arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_GS, foo);`"

Or on a CPU with FSGSBASE, perhaps [`wrgsbase`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) from user-space, if the kernel (such as Linux 5.9 or newer) enables that for user-space use. (`CR4.FSGSBASE[bit 16]` must be set or it faults with #UD).

I know that x86-64 switched to using FS for TLS (32-bit uses GS) because of how the `syscall` entry point uses `swapgs` to find the kernel stack.

I think that was that just for consistency between user and kernel for kernel TLS / per-core stuff, because 32-bit processes under a 64-bit kernel do still use GS for TLS.  Except 32-bit processes can't use `syscall` (except on AMD CPUs).  That alone doesn't rule out some code that only executes for a 64-bit process that could do something with GS, but probably there's no problem.

[`swapgs`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/swapgs) only swaps the GS base, not the selector.  I don't know if there are any kernel entry points that would rewrite GS with some default selector value (and then reload the saved GS base).  I'd guess not.

Comment: Thanks, I want it for detecting interrupts per [this](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2018/01/observing-interrupts-from-userland-on-x86.html).